Can't log back in after suspending in Ubuntu 24.04
I'm experiencing an issue with my Ubuntu 24.04 system. After suspending the computer, I'm unable to log back in. When I try to enter my password, the system does not respond as expected, and I'm unable to regain access.

Operating system - Ubuntu 24.04
Hardware model - HP ProBook 450 G4
Processor - Intel Core i5-7200U × 4
GNOME version - 46


"does not respond as expected" What does the system do?

press ctrl+alt+f3, then at prompt type "kill -3 $(pidof gnome-shell)" to restart gnome.
